# Model not found even with 'use'

Tags: php, frameworks, slim

I'm using Slim Framework and I'm facing an issue. I declare the Model of my module like this :

```
 use \Autofoldering\Models\AutofolderingModel;
```

And after I use a function like this :

```
$stmt = AutofolderingModel::select([
    'select'    => [$distinct ? 'distinct ' . $data: $data],
    'table'     => [$table],
    'where'     => [$where],
    'order_by'  => [$orderBy],
]);
```

And here is the issue I have when I try to execute :

```
 Uncaught Error: Class 'Autofoldering\Models\AutofolderingModel' not found
```

FYI, I use PHPSTORM and I didn't have any error, the class is well charged.

Thanks

Comment: I never used slim framework but it seems that the autoloading wasn't called..

Comment: On an unrelated note, you don't need to pretend the fully-qualified class name with a backslash when importing with a `use` statement.

Comment: As @MateiMihai pointed out, either your autoloading isn't properly set up, or the class doesn't exist.

Comment: Could you please copy the "autoload" part of your composer.json and also give a little more details about your project structure? Where did you define `Autofoldering\Models\AutofolderingModel` class? What is the file name and its path?

Answer (score 0):

did you try to run :

> composer dump-autoload